# Add Visual Composer version 5.1.1 with custom theme but ''setSortable' of undefined

Tags: php, wordpress, visual-composer

Create theme in WordPress but Visual Composer is not working. Please give me solution asp.

Answer (score 0):

You related the question to the WPBakery, not Visual Composer plugin. You need to have the last version 5.7 in order to fix this issue. More information, contact support.wpbakery.com if you have a valid license.